# "duplicate entry" error when exporting Java project to JAR with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am trying to exort a Java project with Eclipse 3.6.1 to a runnable Jar. This used to work properly but failed today, afer I added some additional Jars to my class path.

The error is

```
duplicate entry: some/class.class
```

Interestingly, there is a duplicate entry for almost any class in my buildpath. Even though I did not change anything. The Jars I added do not contain duplicate classes.

Question: Is this some kind of Eclipse bug? Am I ovrlooking something obvious? Does anybody have an idea what could cause this error?

Cheers

Comment: If you've generated the ant build script could you post it.

Comment: Here's my Ant script as generated by Eclipse: http://typewith.me/M6bAQ7pUCe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try modifying the line

```
<jar destfile="/Volumes/resi/talosBase.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
```

in your build file to be

```
<jar destfile="/Volumes/resi/talosBase.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain" duplicate="preserve">
```

This will cause ant to preserve the first entry of any duplicate and ignore the rest. The default behavious is "add" so you can end up with multiple files of the same fully qualified name. The other valid entry for this paramter is "fail" but I don't think that will help you here.

---

OLD-Answer

Delete your last created runnable jar either manually or alter the generated ant script to do so before creating a new one

Comment: Please see edited answer - not sure if you get a message when someone edits it or not but you should get one about this comment.

Comment: Thanks! I never used ant scripts before (only Eclipse -> export jar), but now I couldn't live without it.

Comment: @KevinD where should I modify this line

Comment: @chopss Did you ever find out where this line was?

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning the project should help. It is not eclipse bug, but rather jar maker's one. Apparantly, it takes the classes and see that such classes already exist and can't understand that it should replace them instead of adding.

Comment: How can I clean the project with respect to buildpath/Jars?

Comment: Found it ... cleaning does not have any effect on the behaviour when generating a runnable Jar. Any oth er idea?

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning the project will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem, but then I slightly modified the build settings in Eclipse to the one mentioned below.

[image: Eclipse export jar]

This solved the duplicate entry issue for me, it just copies all required jars to a subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

in my case cleaning the project doesnt change any thing so i use a workaround  :

1. genearte a build script by activation by save ANT script [ant script genration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f96U4.png)
2. execute the ant script manually or in eclipse (its better)
   [executing script by eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Z32.png)

and I change my ant build script by adding option as indicate in this post duplicate="preserve" (to keep the first version on the duplicated file )

hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the jars and adding it once again.. this got the error resolved for me..