# JarSplice not working ("Duplicate entry")

Tags: java, jar

I am using the JarSplice tool to create a runnable jar file.

However, as soon as I add lwjgl.jar to my required jar files, it immediately fails to create the jar, saying
"Duplicate entry".

Here is a screenshot of the error: http://gyazo.com/2aac58aa15ba19ff7c61aeda548f43c2

If I remove lwjgl.jar it obviously builds the jar file, but cannot run because I require LWJGL.jar

And here is a screenshot of the added jar files: http://gyazo.com/78a88443336bfb530ed71bd6418e9be1

So, how can I fix this "Duplicate entry" issue so I can create my fat jar file?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["duplicate entry" error when exporting Java project to JAR with Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378074/duplicate-entry-error-when-exporting-java-project-to-jar-with-eclipse)